# Why my for loop is overwriting the variable instead appending?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to convert multiple columns from float into string type from a dataframe.

I have a dataframe below:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'User':['101','102','103','104','105','106'],'CountA':[7,8,9,10,11,12],'CountB':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'CountC':[13,14,15,16,17,18]})
```

I am trying to convert column "CountA" and "CountB" into string using for loop:

```py
convert = (df["CountA"], df["CountB"])
col_name = ["CountA","CountB"]
```

```py
for a in convert:
       for b in col_name:
           df[b] = a.astype(str)
```

After converting using for loop my CountA value replaced by CountB value as below:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'User':['101','102','103','104','105','106'],'CountA':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'CountB':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'CountC':[13,14,15,16,17,18]})
```

What has happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop, you are changing their places twice. The first time, it makes the right replacement. The second iteration switches them.

Use this one instead:

```
for a,b in zip(convert,col_name):
    df[b] = a.astype(str)
```

Or an easier option is this:

```
df[["CountA","CountB"]] = df[["CountA","CountB"]].astype(str)
```

Comment: i am trying to develop my understanding on for loop and i just know about zip() method. thanks for your help!

Comment: zip enables you to select two items at the same time from two different lists. Please find this https://pythonprogramming.net/zip-intermediate-python-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is change the data type of the columns from int to string, why not simply do the following:

```
col_name = ["CountA","CountB"]
for col in col_name:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('str')
```